# simple order by clause not working with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

this query is simply not ordering results the way i want it to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select s.*, p.label, p.number
                    from `sales` as s 
                    left join `pumps` as p on (p.id = s.id_pump)
                    where s.the_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    order by CAST(s.amount_sale AS int) desc
                    limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

i am getting a mysql error.

Comment: nevermind, amount_sale is a VARCHAR. is there a way to convert it to an integer within this query so it is ordered properly?

Comment: `ORDER BY CAST(s.amount_sale AS int)`

Comment: do you actually get a list of values( as you are limiting to only 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the VARCHAR to a signed integer:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select s.*, p.label, p.number
                    from `sales` as s 
                    left join `pumps` as p on (p.id = s.id_pump)
                    where s.the_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    order by CAST(s.amount_sale AS SIGNED) desc
                    limit 1");
```

Comment: perfect thank you! casting it as an int was throwing an error. i learned a new function today...yay.